# I want to count the characters I have put in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

Hi guys I've got a nice code in javascript which writes some characters on the HTML5 Canvas, I want to count the characters on the canvas.
If the canvas counts more then 10.000 characters I want the script to clear the interval.
Here is my code:

```
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
        var lin2=200; // sets the vertical size to 200
        setInterval(function(){
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="black"; //sets the stroke color
ctx.font="20px Georgia"; //set's up the font type and size
ctx.fillStyle="lime";
ctx.fillText(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0,Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1,lin2); //return's random 1 or 0 with random width and lin2 width
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(500,0);
ctx.shadowColor="blue"; // not necessary
ctx.stroke();
var url = c.toDataURL();document.getElementById("mywork").innerHTML="<img src=\""+url+"\"></img>"; // draw it on the canvas
lin2++;  //lin2 +1
if(lin2 > 1200){ //if the vertical height equals the height of the canvas set the vertical heigth to zero.
lin2=0;
}
},0.1); //time delay
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Just the solution, I just don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using `requestAnimationFrame` and a counter to limit the number of loops executed:

[image]

Here's annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/P44MV/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // animation related variables
    var counter=0;
    var lastTime;
    var lin2=200;
    var maxLoops=canvas.height*2;
    var duration=0.20;

    // set the styles once before animating
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";
    ctx.font="20px Georgia";
    ctx.fillStyle="lime";

    // start the animation loops
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate(t){

        // exits after the doing the desire count of loops
        if(counter++ > maxLoops){return;}

        // we're not done, so request another loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // calculate  elapsed time since the last loop
        if(!lastTime){lastTime=t;}
        var elapsedTime=t-lastTime;
        // exit if sufficient elapsed time hasn't occurred.
        if(elapsedTime<duration){return;}
        // reset the lastTime for the next loop
        lastTime=t;

        // draw a random 0 or 1 at a random X on the canvas
        var x=Math.random()*canvas.width-5;
        ctx.fillText( parseInt(Math.random()+0.50), x, lin2);

        // increment the loop counter and lin2
        counter++;
        lin2++;
        // reset lin2 if it exceeds the canvas height
        if(lin2>canvas.height){lin2=10;}

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=650></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SemVoigtländer.  Just out of curiosity, why did you un-accept my answer? :-)

Comment: I thought I did Accept your answer? Must went something wrong? I am sorry. How can I accept It? I am really new to Stack

Answer (score 1):

You can't count text in your canvas as soon as it's drawn.

What you can do instead is count it yourself, e.g..:

```
var totalText = 0;
window.onload = function() {
    var lin2=200; // sets the vertical size to 200
    setInterval(function(){
        var txt = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0,Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1,lin2);
        totalText += txt.length;
        // some more of your code
        ctx.fillText(txt);
    // …
```

And as a side note, if you want to clear the interval you have to store it somewhere.

Comment: Now he wont drive it on the canvas anymore

Comment: Well, technically you just need to store the text in a variable to retrieve the length and then print it. My snippet might not be functional as I would end up rewriting most of it but should get you going or point you in the right direction at least…